# JWT authentication module not being recognized in django rest api even after being installed

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm implementing JWT authentication in my API made from Django. I installed the recommended package (rest_framework_jwt) and added it to the required files according to the documentation. However, upon running the server, I'm getting the following error:-

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'
```

Here is my settings.py file:-

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-uh*2t%%^q0mzj!5r@9=7i$!16wwm)96e=-zh)8&l)-&d3(_!)i'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = int(os.environ.get('DEBUG',default=0))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    #3rd party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',


    #local apps
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stackstagram.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stackstagram.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'postgres',
        'HOST':'db',
        'PORT':5432

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFUALT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
SITE_ID = 1
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR/'media')
```

Here is my project level urls.py file:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('api-auth/',include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/v1/rest-auth/',include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api/v1/rest-auth/registration/',include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: please add 'rest_framework_simplejwt', in installed apps 
its not token.blacklist its just rest_framework_simplejwt

Comment: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html
look into orignal doc

Comment: still not working, it's showing the same error

Comment: have you activat your virtualenviroment and make sure requirements are install in that enviroment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
pip install --upgrade djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

Comment: I did, still the same error